# save data depending on passed value in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save time taken to complete each level. so im looking for a better way to save data, i have 100 variables for all levels i.e, leveltime1, levetime2....and so on..leveltime100
I have this code which is not working

```
var leveltime : [Int] = [leveltime1, levetime2, leveltime3......leveltime100]
defaults.setInteger("leveltime[Currentlevel -1]")
leveltime[Currentlevel -1] = defaults.integerForKey("leveltime[Currentlevel -1]")
```

so this is not working. is there any other way ? other than if else and switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets assume you are in level `3` and want to save the time you needed

```
var level = 3
var time = 21
```

now you want to safe this to your defaults, for this you generate a key (string)

```
var key = "leveltime-\(level)"
```

and store the time

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(time,key)
```

done.

to retrieve this at some point in time

```
var level = 3
var key = "leveltime-\(level)"
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var time = defaults.integerForKey(key)
```

Comment: runs just fine here. the upper one will likely not work as you expect as it does not convert the level number in the string, try the second block :)

Comment: check this out http://i.imgur.com/WhZowaQ.png and console http://i.imgur.com/ur33c3P.png when i started the app , all 4 levels were 0 , as u can see i completed 4 levels in 7,9.. seconds and then went back to main menu and value was still 0 0 0 0

Comment: may b its saving for "levelkey" but timelevel1...2.3

Comment: you changed my answer :) you are saving all results to "levelkey". there is no need for the `"` there. look at my code again. `forKey: levelkey` not `forKey: "levelkey"` :) levelkey is already a string, you do not need to put it in "".

Comment: still no luck, looks like ill have to go with switch or if else statement which will take over 300 lines

Comment: no you dont! this solutions works 100%, you must have made a error somewhere :) please update your post with the new code you have running now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67979/discussion-between-sebastian-fluckiger-and-djay).